# Laravel 5.3 Scaffold CRUD from existing database

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.3, scaffolding

i have an existing database and all my models are defined already. I would like to **scaffold Controllers and Views** because it's really time consuming.

i found this which sound good: [infyom](http://labs.infyom.com/laravelgenerator/docs/5.3/introduction)
They say in the documentation that you can use it from an existing database but any command keeps asking me for fields, (as it is trying to create a model from scratch), what i want to to use my existing models.

I found the "scaffold from table" option in the documentation:

```
php artisan infyom:scaffold Equipement --fromTable --tableName=Equipement
```

But it says:`[ErrorException]
  Undefined index: Equipement`

i guess it did not find my existing model.
I was wondering, what do they call `datatable` anyway ? I can see in their config file they have a folder for that, maybe i should define my models there somehow ?

Thanks for anyone who can help on that. (or providing an alternative solution for scaffolding from existing database/models)

Answer (score 0):

You must add `id` and:

```
updated_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
deleted_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL
```

in your table.